# My React app is showing a blank page after being deployed on Vercel

Tags: deployment, vercel

I have a React app deployed on Vercel that is encountering an issue. The browser console is logging an error that says ‘rh is not a function’, even though it works fine locally and there were no errors during build time

My app uses React version 18.0.0 and react-router and vite.

I have checked all of my code and found no errors. I also added the ‘homepage: ‘.’’ field to package.json, but it still isn’t working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the error originated from the dayjs library. After deleting it, my project was deployed perfectly.